# Is it safe to use Giphy API keys in public Github repo?

Tags: web-application, cryptography, privacy, api, github

I am making a game of which one of the hidden features is displaying a GIF from Giphy at a fixed command. For this, I am using [Giphy API](https://developers.giphy.com/docs/#operation--gifs-search-get), hosting the game as a website on Github Pages with a public repo, and getting the data with a `get` request.

But since this is my first time using an API key, I wanted to know if it is secure to use API key as such in a public repo, or what should be the ideal way to access the data using the key in this case?

Comment: What can an evil supervillain do with your Giphy API key?

Comment: At least, encode or encrypt so that it would not be picked up by bots.

Comment: @user253751 Overrun your rate limits. In a heartbeat. It's called DOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here is the official response to this question from GIPHY:
>
> > GIPHY APIs are designed to be used on the client side (and hence the API key too). You should go ahead and use it that way. Once development is complete - please apply for Production access for the key through the Developer Dashboard, this removes Rate limits associated with a beta key, so you don't have to worry about high traffic.
> > Lastly, and most importantly - GIPHY has monitors setup for API key abuse and we'll reach out to you if anything happens. We definitely don't want you to worry about it.

[From here](https://github.com/Giphy/giphy-js/issues/120#issuecomment-680988917)